# How I rewrite this code in VueJS using v-for?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

How I use the following code in vuejs using v-for?

```
@php $rating = 3; @endphp

@foreach(range(1,5) as $r)
<span class="fa-stack" style="width:1em">
    <i class="far fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>

    @if($rating >0)
        @if($rating >0.5)
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
        @else
          <i class="fas fa-star-half fa-stack-1x"></i>
        @endif
    @endif

    @php $rating--; @endphp
</span>
@endforeach
```

I used following method. But I have no idea how I decrement rating.

```
<span class="fa-stack" style="width:1em" v-for="r in 5">
    <i class="far fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-stack-1x" v-if="product.average_rating > 0  && product.average_rating > 0.5"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half fa-stack-1x" v-if="product.average_rating > 0  && !(product.average_rating > 0.5)"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Migrating laravel template using vuejs

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do in the same way as in blade, but if it is `product.average_rating` that you want to decrement, then you could replace `product.average_rating` with `(product.average_rating - r + 1)` everywhere in the code block you provided. Like this:

```
<span class="fa-stack" style="width:1em" v-for="r in 5">
    <i class="far fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-stack-1x" v-if="(product.average_rating - r + 1) > 0  && (product.average_rating - r + 1) > 0.5"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half fa-stack-1x" v-if="(product.average_rating - r + 1) > 0  && !((product.average_rating - r + 1) > 0.5)"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @UttaraInfoTech updated my answer with the example.